# scrollview not scrolling all the way down with setcontentsize call

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

it has been asked but the answer I applied doesn't work

I created a scrollView outlet to my scroolView

When sliding down, it cuts off half the page so I added

in viewdidload

It's like this line doesn't affect it...

Thank you in advance

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure the frame size is within the visible view. if the frame extends outside the visible view, thats when you'll see the scrollview not scrolling all the way

try by setting the height to half of what it is and then see if it scrolls all the way. from there on, you can figure out whats the required frame size for your scroll view

Comment: by frame size you mean in interface builder? or in this line?

Comment: in the interface builder or in code (its an additional line of code you'll have to add)